# Jung, graph with gui/jframe as node

Tags: java, user-interface, jung

I am playing with the JUNG library and I want to create a graph, whose nodes are some gui(jframe presumably) items.

I want each of the nodes to have a few buttons, one text field, menu, etc.

And my question is: is this possible?

If yes, I have two other questions:
1. How should I approach it(I am new to Java and I am not familiar with the best practices )
2. What interface should I use(I am looking at .visualisation.decorators.* currenlty).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OK, eventually I succeeded creating a graph of JPanels and JFrames. I will continue with JPanels. And here is the result:

[image]

But now I face some other problems:

1. The frames can be moved, but only if they are picked at the upper left corner. How can I make the whole JPanel area pickable?
2. I need the JPanels to be accessible, e.g. I should be able to press the button, write some text in a textbox(this is not implemented yet) and probably resize the JPanel. Currently the JPanels are "inactive/no focus" for some reason. I tried the enable method, no success. Tried some "focus" methods, again failed.

Any suggestions on the above two questions?

Here is how my code looks like:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.CellRendererPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.CircleLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.Layout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.DirectedSparseGraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.RenderContext;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationViewer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.control.DefaultModalGraphMouse;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.control.ModalGraphMouse;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.picking.PickedState;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.renderers.Renderer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.transform.shape.GraphicsDecorator;

public class GraphPanel extends Container
{
    static final long serialVersionUID = 420001L;
    DirectedSparseGraph<Number, Number> graph = null;
    VisualizationViewer<Number, Number> vv = null;
    PickedState<Number> pickedState = null;

    public GraphPanel(Number[][] nodes_list)
    {
        try
        {
            graph = new DirectedSparseGraph<Number, Number>();
            construct_graph(nodes_list);

            vv = new VisualizationViewer<Number, Number>
                        (new CircleLayout<Number, Number>(graph), new Dimension(400, 400));
            vv.getRenderer().setVertexRenderer(new MyRenderer());

            // The vertex pick listener
            pickedState = vv.getPickedVertexState();
            pickedState.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
                {
                    Object subject = e.getItem();
                    if (subject instanceof Number)
                    {
                        Number vertex = (Number) subject;
                        if (pickedState.isPicked(vertex))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Vertex " + vertex + " is now selected");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Vertex " + vertex + " no longer selected");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            // The following code adds capability for mouse picking of
            // vertices/edges. Vertices can even be moved!
            final DefaultModalGraphMouse<Number, Number> graphMouse = new DefaultModalGraphMouse<Number, Number>();
            vv.setGraphMouse(graphMouse);
            graphMouse.setMode(ModalGraphMouse.Mode.PICKING);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Failed to construct graph!\n");
            System.err.println("Caught Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /*Attach the graph panel/container to a specified frame*/
    public void attach_to_frame(JFrame frame)
    {
        frame.setContentPane(vv);
    }

    /*This one should be reimplemented*/
    private void construct_graph(Number[][] nodes_list)
    {
        int i = 0;
        /*add the nodes*/
        for(i=0; i<nodes_list.length; i++)
        {
            graph.addVertex(i);
            graph.addEdge(nodes_list[i][0], nodes_list[i][1], nodes_list[i][2]);
        }
    }

    /*re-implement the render functionality to work with internal frames(JInternalFrame)*/
    static class MyRenderer extends JPanel implements Renderer.Vertex<Number, Number>
    {
        static final long serialVersionUID = 420000L;
        @Override
        public void paintVertex(RenderContext<Number, Number> rc,
                                Layout<Number, Number> layout, Number vertex)
        {
            try
            {
                GraphicsDecorator graphicsContext = rc.getGraphicsContext();
                Point2D center = layout.transform(vertex);
                Dimension size = new Dimension(100, 80);

                System.out.printf("Vertex[%d] X = %d Y = %d: Running paintVertex()\n", vertex, (int)center.getX(), (int)center.getY());

                JPanel sv = new JPanel();
                sv.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
                sv.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                sv.setPreferredSize(size);
                sv.add(new JButton("Button1"));
                //OK
                graphicsContext.draw(sv, rc.getRendererPane(), (int)center.getX(), 
                                     (int)center.getY(), size.width, size.height, true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println("Failed to render images!\n");
                System.err.println("Caught Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        /*Create the window*/
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BLABLA");
        Number[][] list = {{0, 1, 3}, {1, 3, 1}, {2, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 0}};
        GraphPanel g = new GraphPanel(list);
        g.attach_to_frame(frame);
        frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}/*2*/
```

Comment: This isn't going to help much but maybe it will push you in some sort of direction: the JPanels probably aren't receiving input (focus) because it's being intercepted before it can get to them. Try listening for the focus on every one of your GUI components and see which is grabbing the focus first. Then, you might be able to propagate the focus to the correct component.

Comment: And it might be a better idea to rephrase these as two, new, individual questions.

Comment: Indeed, the Focus is only on the Visualization Viewer, e.g. on the underlying panel. And it never moves to the Vertex Panels(the green ones). I will check now how to move the focus to them.

Any suggestions will be appreciated?

Comment: I've not run into the problem myself, but I can guarantee that if you phrase it as a new question that you'll get some references to solutions - I'm sure it's been asked before.

Comment: OK I will put it as a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible (I think).  I would recommend you change your VertexLabeler to one that you implement yourself.  Something in the lines of...

```
VisualizationImageServer<V, E> vv = new ...;
vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelRenderer(new MyVertexRenderer());

class MyVertexRenderer extends JFrame implements VertexLabelRenderer {}
```

But I'm not sure how it is going to work in terms of positioning it later.  You might need to change the `VertexShapeTransofrmer` aswell with `vv.getRenderContext().setVertexShapeTransformer()`.

I must say, I've spent a lot of time trying to get Jung to render a graph nicely like [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) with very little success.